# Autolayout NSCollectionView with subviews

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have an NSCollectionView in one .xib and 
the subview collection view item for that collection view in another .xib

I am trying to add constraints to my collection view item in order to 
let it to

1. Align the edges with the superview's view
2. Resize itself according to the superview

The collection view item in this second .xib is a NSTableView with constraints as shown in the attachment.

[image: Constraints configuration]

Upon startup I get the following

1. The superview, i.e NSCollectionView is larger than its subviews.
2. If I resize the entire window and make it smaller, the NSCollectionView will resize itself too, but the subviews do not. See second attachment.

[image]

Comment: The items usually provide their size to the collection view, which then lays them out in a grid. It doesn't make much sense to have the items try to conform themselves to a size provided by the collection view. How would the collection view pick a size? That said, you can set a minimum and maximum item size on the collection view.

Comment: I see. It is possible to achieve this with NSScrollView? I know that NSCollectionView is embedded in a NSScrollView

Comment: Achieve what? How would you like the size of the items in the collection view to be determined? You can make them whatever size you want.

Comment: @KenThomases Achieve that the subviews resize themselves according to its container. That doesn't sound to be a very unusual scenario, right? Perhaps the NSCollectionView should be replaced by another view?

Comment: What container? The collection view? What portion of the collection view should each item get? How should that be calculated? Are you setting a fixed number of row and columns on your collection view?

Comment: Usually, a collection view is in a scroll view. The width of the scroll view determines the width of the collection view. Each item determines its own size. The number of columns is the width of the collection view divided by the width of an item. The number of rows is the number of items divided by the number of columns, rounded up. The collection view height is the number of rows times the height of an item. It scrolls if it's taller than the scroll view.

Comment: @KenThomases The collection view container, sure. I have set rows = 1 and columns = 0. Each item should have equal size + spacing between the items. Also it should stretch vertically and align with the bottom edge of the container (collection view).

Comment: `NSCollectionView` won't do what you want. Given the fairly simple, single-row layout, you may be able to use an `NSStackView`. You'll be responsible for adding a view per represented object, but the stack view will lay them out horizontally. Vertically, you can set up constraints between the contained views' edges and the stack view's edges.

Comment: @KenThomases would a `NSScrollView` do it too? Thinking it might be more flexible to use a class that exists in < 10.9

Comment: A scroll view won't do anything but provide scrolling for a content view that's larger than it. You could make the moral equivalent of a stack view by just creating a plain `NSView` as your container and then fill it with subviews. Set the layout constraints to keep the subviews arranged how you like within it and to keep the plain view wide enough to contain them all. Set the plain view to be as tall as the clip view and the subviews as tall as the view. Make sure the subviews are flexible in their height at least relative to the priority of the view-to-clip-view constraints.

Comment: I'll try that. You may post your comment as an answer and then I'll accept it. Obviously I won't get where I want with just a NSCollectionView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSCollectionView` won't do what you want. The items provide their size to the collection view, which then lays them out in a grid.

Given the fairly simple, single-row layout you're trying to achieve, you may be able to use an `NSStackView`. If you don't want to require 10.9 or later, you could make the moral equivalent of a stack view by just creating a plain NSView as your container and then fill it with subviews. You would put this view into a scroll view. The container view would have constraints to keep its top and bottom equal to the clip view's. Its width would not be related to the clip view's. (I don't know if you want the container view's leading edge tied to the clip view's. That might require some experimentation.)

Set the layout constraints to keep the subviews arranged how you like within the container view and to keep it wide enough to contain them all. You'll want constraints to keep the tops of the subviews related to the top of the container view and similarly for the bottoms. However, make sure the subviews are flexible in their height at least relative to the priority of the view-to-clip-view constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achieve what you describe with NSCollectionView by setting the itemSize equal to the collection view's width in the FlowLayoutDelegate while calling `collectionView.collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()` in `viewWillLayout` in the view controller to handle resizing.